# How to Deal with Null (GridView Container.DataItem)

Tags: asp.net, gridview

whats wrong here, why is it complaining about closing the `")"` ?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>   
                        <%# FixNull((namespace.Student)(Container.DataItem), "Name"); %>               
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                       <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlStudent" runat="server" datasourceid="CountyDataSource"
                            datatextfield="Name" datavaluefield="Id" autopostback="false">
                        </asp:dropdownlist>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

 protected string FixNull(object dataItem, string fieldName)
 {
        if (dataItem != null)
        {
            System.Data.DataRowView cls = (System.Data.DataRowView)dataItem;
            if (!cls.Row.IsNull(fieldName))
                return (cls[fieldName]).ToString();
            else
                return "&nbsp;";
        }
        else
            return "&nbsp;";
    }



Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

Source Error: Line: 133 


Line 131:                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
Line 132:                    <ItemTemplate>   
Line 133:    <%# FixNull((namespace.Student)(Container.DataItem), "Name"); %>               
Line 134:                    </ItemTemplate>
Line 135:                    <EditItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%# Eval("CountyName") == null ? "&nbsp;" : Eval("CountyName")%>
```

Comment: Simple but effective soln. Nice one.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you do not need the `;`

it should just read:

`<%# FixNull((namespace.Student)(Container.DataItem), "Name") %>`

Comment: @Abu Hamzah: Ok well, your original problem is solved :) -- However for the new errors you are getting, I would start by asking why are you casting `Container.DataItem` to `namespace.Student`? In your method you are expecting an object, so why cast it to that type? Just think about that and fix it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify further you could use

```
<%# this.Eval("CountyName") ?? "&nbsp;"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
    <ItemTemplate>   
        <%# FixNull(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name"))%>               
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:dropdownlist id="ddlStudent" runat="server" datasourceid="CountyDataSource"
            datatextfield="Name" datavaluefield="Id" autopostback="false">
        </asp:dropdownlist>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>


protected string FixNull(string dataItem)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataItem))
    {
        return dataItem;
    }
    return "&nbsp;";
}
```

Comment: does not work, you passing the two parameters and you have are expecting on parameter in your FixNull ?